# Getting most frequent values between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a table with these columns:

```
date | station
```

`Date` is a `datetime` column.

`Station` is just a number between 1 and 110.

I need to return most frequent station values between 1 and 26 for last month.
I did it for today already and it works (code below). But I don't know how to make it for whole month.

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM   table    
WHERE  YEAR(Time_Stamp) = YEAR(GETDATE())   AND
       MONT(Time_Stamp) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND
       DAY(Time_Stamp) = DAY(GETDATE())   AND 
       station BETWEEN 1 AND 26 
GROUP BY station
ORDER BY count(1) desc
```

Comment: Share your sample data as well as expected output.

Comment: Well... you could simply comment out the `day(...) = ...` part.